# Github extension seems to have disappeared from Team Explorer in VS 15?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I've been using VS for a while and have always pushed my code to github from within VS. I've just started a new project and want to do the same thing but in the Team Explorer github no longer appears. The options are either Team Services or Publish to a remote repository created outside of VS (which I understand in theory could be github but usually there is a github option within Team Explorer).

I've just created a new project called Test and github doesn't appear in this project either.

Anyone encountered this problem? And where can I check to see if the github extension is still installed?

Cheers,

Jerome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the same thing so I checked my `Extensions and Updates` and it looked like the Github extension uninstalled itself.

Searching the "online" pane for "github" allowed me to reinstall and now it's working again. Hope this helps.

You can access your `Extensions and Updates` by clicking on the Tools menu and it's about 3/4 of the way down the menu.